# FindOrCreate with 2 unique columns

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Iam using sequelise orm. I have simple model with 2 unique columns

```
const DataTypes =  require('sequelize')
const orm = require('./../builder')

module.exports = orm.define('users', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },
  login: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },
  password_hash: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
    allowNull: false
  }
},
{
  indexes: [
    {
      unique: true,
      fields: ['email', 'login']
    }
  ],
  timestamps: false
})
```

And i want to create row without duoplicates. I just using findOrCreate transactions method:

```
    Users.sequelize.transaction((tx) => {
  return Users.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      email: email,
      login: login
    },
    defaults: {
      password_hash: passwordHash
    }
  })
})
.spread((user, created) => {
  console.log(created)
  console.log(user.get({
    plain: true
  }))
})
```

When I send and after all different parameterseverything works great. But if i sent one of two values difference and second which equal to if I've got an error `Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error`
Example for working params: 
First record:

```
 {
    'email': 'x',
    'login': 'y',
    'password_hash': 123
}
```

Second record:

```
 {
    'email': 'z',
    'login': 's',
    'password_hash': 123
}
```

Example for not working params:
First record:

```
 {
    'email': 'x',
    'login': 'y',
    'password_hash': 123
}
```

Second record:

```
 {
    'email': 'x',
    'login': 'z',
    'password_hash': 123
}
```